# Create a HTML bundle?

Tags: websites, html, archive

How can I create a bundle of HTML/CSS/JS/Image files that can be double-clicked to bring up a web browser? Ideally I would like to be able to use an icon on the file as well.

Is there a plugin for Chrome or Firefox that I could use to save page as a bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari and TextEdit allow you to create a .webarchive package.

What I'd recommend is creating your site and open it in Safari to save it as .webarchive.

I'm not sure about customizing the icon… not sure if that is supported for webarchive bundles.

Comment: You can change the icon the same way you change icons for any file, command + i, then highlight the icon in the top left hand corner next to the name and paste the image you want. However with webarchives, the preview wont change. it'll stay a page with content